# нужно сделать событие на клавишу ctr? с++

Tags: c++

пытался делать так:

```
char a = _getch();
    if (a == 0x11)
        cout << "u enter ctr";
```

но ничего не выводит(

Comment: Не зачем плодить дубликаты.

Comment: там не тот ответ... мда

Comment: Если вам нужен полноценный ввод, то тогда нужно делать окно и полноценный цикл сообщений.